# Zabbix: get triggers excluding some triggers by triggerid

Tags: zabbix

I use Zabbix API method `trigger.get` to retrieve a list of available triggers. I try to exclude some triggers from the result list by passing their ids into `params`:

```
"excludeSearch": "true",
"search": {"triggerid": "37328"}
```

It doesn't seem to exclude the trigger with the given id. In the [manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference_commentary#common_get_method_parameters%20manual) I read:

`search` Works only for string and text fields.

I am not sure if it applies to `triggerid` which is

`triggerids string/array`

Anyway, is there any other way to get exclusion by triggerid working?

PS. I tried other names for that parameter, i.e. `triggerid`, `triggerids`, and experimented with passing value arrays, objects etc.

Comment: Do you want to exclude (avoid, skip) those triggers or limit the result to those triggers only (limit, filter by, include)?

Comment: exclude (avoid, skip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to exclude triggers by ID in `trigger.get`. The confusion regarding string/not is understandable - the API documentation you quote that says "string/array" is looking at this from the API perspective, while the "Works only for string and text fields" part talks about the database field types. The trigger ID is a numeric field in the DB, thus it cannot be searched - and filtering for it cannot be reversed either.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes, it's confusing indeed. The doc for the trigger object, https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/trigger/object, some properties (e.g. triggerid) are listed as `string`, some as `integer` (status), both represented by numbers.

Comment: String/integer difference is normal, though. That's what the API expects there, and if you would pass some longer IDs as numbers, the results would be very unexpected.